# Let $a_n \to 0$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} (a_{n+1}-a_n)n $ equals to ??

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $a_n \to 0.$

Then  $$\lim_{n \to \infty} (a_{n+1}-a_n)n $$   equals to ??

I have taken a few examples and got that the limit equals to zero. It seems that the limit is zero, but how to prove it in general ?

or my guess is wrong...

Please provide some hint. Thank you.

Comment: Interestingly, this limit is true under the stronger assumption that $a_n$ is summable and monotonic.

Comment: @Zhanxiong with your example limit is zero.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Your counter example is apparently wrong, the limit is $0$ in your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if your sequence is monotone, this may not be true.
If you consider $a_{k}=\frac{1}{n}$ for $n^3\leq k<(n+1)^3 $, then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_{n^3}-a_{n^3-1})(n^3-1)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n-1}\right)(n^3-1)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^3-1}{n-n^2}=-\infty$$ So, $\{(a_{n^3}-a_{n^3-1})(n^3-1)\}$is a divergent subsequence of $\{(a_{n+1}-a_n)n\}$.

Answer (score 4):

No general conclusion here. For example let $a_n$ be the sequence
$$0,1/2,0,1/4,0,1/6,\cdots$$
You have
$$(a_{2k+1}-a_{2k})(2k)=-\frac{2k}{2k}=-1$$
and
$$(a_{2k}-a_{2k-1})(2k-1)=\frac{2k-1}{2k}\to1$$

Answer (score 2):

Your guess is wrong.
Consider $a_n=(-1)^n/\sqrt{n}, n\geq 1$ Then $$n(a_{n+1}-a_n)=(-1)^{n+1}n(1/\sqrt{n+1})+1/\sqrt{n}).$$

However, $n(1/\sqrt{n+1}+1/\sqrt{n})>2\sqrt{n}\to +\infty$, which excludes
$(-1)^{n+1}n(1/\sqrt{n+2}+1/\sqrt{n+1})\to 0$.